# How to handle same third party library header name confliction in xcode when building ios framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, eigen

Trying to build a framework for ios in xcode, library `Eigen` and `Foundation.framework` are both used. The code was as following:

```
a.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Error are :

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
/Users/blob/3rdparty/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:18:21: error: 'XprType' does not refer to a value
struct traits<Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel> > : traits<XprType>
```

The problem is that there are two `Block.h` and the compiler find the wrong one. How to solve it?

**Solved**

Finally solved! When add Eigen folder to project, un-check the `Add to target` in the option panel. But I do not know why.

Comment: Please post the code where you have the `#include`.

Comment: @user1118321 Just a simple include

Comment: Don't edit an answer into the question. You can answer your own question instead